# Ubuntu update failed on BQ Aquaris M10

Tags: ubuntu-touch, aquaris

A system update (I think it's OTA11) downloaded and started to install. It completed the 800ish MB download. A dialog box then said "Sorry the update failed to install".

What do I do now?

I've not done anything 'interesting' with the device so it's configured how it came out of the box. I retried the install but it started to re-download the 800MB again so I cancelled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly same experience. Reboot, and retry and it worked. It took longer than I ecpected, but waited patiently.

Comment: Same here. Both OTA-11 & OTA-12 updates failed at the first try for me, but successfully  completed in the second go.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't want to waste the megabytes, but I'll do it again if there's a good chance.

Comment: It worked after a restart and new attempt.

Answer (score 2):

I have two tablets, which I updated last night with the OTA-12. The funny thing is that the one downloaded the update all OK and then installed it quite quick. No issues at all. However, the second tablet stopped half way during the download. So I restarted it and checked for updates. It told me that there were none available. So I rebooted again and checked. This time the OTA-12 was there to download. It took a really long time to download and then install. I would say 15 minutes for both. However, after the reboots, it all went OK and I am now using OTA-12 on both tablets.

Comment: Glad you got there. A second try worked for me too. You'd think there would be better error reporting...